# var DB*; in C++

Tags: c++

My professor sent back a short email:

```
int x = 100;
var HT*;
HT = new int[x];
```

Firstly:
Compiling the code (with other stuff around it to make it "work"):
error: 'var' does not name a type.

Second:
This is for hash tables. Apparently this is the way to create an array of variable size according to the ANSI standard (G++ has extensions that we can't use or he'll shoot us).

Any ideas?

Comment: `int *HT;` would make much more sense - the above isn't a syntax I'm familiar with.

Comment: Tell your professor to use `std::vector`.

Comment: @Johnny: It's a dynamic array container from the standard library. You should really get [a book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) on C++ so you can program good C++.

Comment: One more piece of off-topic advice: Consider giving more self-explanatory names to your variables. If you, one day, have 10,000 lines of code full of names such as `x`, `i`, `HT`, `qm`, `st`, etc., you're more likely to suffer from it (trying to understand what's going on) than to benefit (from having had to type less).

Comment: I guess with `var` he meant `int` or `double` or ... . And by the way, as C++98 is also an ISO standard, even in the US you can refer to C++98 as an ISO rather than an ANSI standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var HT*` is not valid C++ syntax (looks C#-inspired to me;-) -- `int *HT` is how, in C++, you declare `HT` to be a pointer to integer (which can hold the result of an array-`new` -- you'll have to remember to use `delete[]` and not plain `delete` when you're done, though!).

Answer (score 1):

It should be `auto` which is the equivalent of `var` in C#. But I think, if your professor does not allow usage of `std::vector`, he or she will neither allow usage of `std::array` nor the c++0x code elements. To my knowledge there is no `var` keyword wheter present nor intended in standard c++. There is one in C++/CLI, but after what I have red, if you just mention this acronym your professor gets a heart attack...

Answer (score 0):

change the `var` to an `int` which should get rid of the first error.

Comment: not sufficient: the star is also in the wrong place, _after_ the identifier being declared and defined, while it should be _before_ it (see my answer).